# Nested div - size of the child

Tags: html, css

Today I encountered situation where in-house library is used to create popups for web-application. In my case, this popup will contain single paragraph with text, and we can not assume anything about the amount of this text.

When I investigated the `html` that is generated by this library for this popup, there are some nested `div` elements, and at the lowest level there is a `div` for header, body and a footer.

As one of the parameters to the function that is creating popup object I can pass hardcoded width and height of the body part (as a json object), but I am only limited to this option, if nothing is passed, defaults are assumed so the body can only have some height/width specified (at the current time I can't pass other parameters for direct styling).

I wanted to go around this problem by putting my paragraph in it's own `div` to which I have access.

Now, the problem is that when the text is taking more space then outer div`div`, the outer `div` size remains the same, and the text seems to be 'leaking' from the popup.

I tried with something like this (adding `overflow:auto` to the style of the inner `div`)

```
<div class="popup-body" style="width: 450px; height: 460px">
    <div class="my-content-div" style="overflow:auto>
        //text in paragraph
    </div>
</div>
```

if I use in `my-content-div` `height:inherit` or `height: 100%` I can get the result I want, the thing is that I can't use `height:inherit` because it is not supported in IE7 (and our application must support IE since version 7) and I can't specify the height in percents, like `height:100%` (now I can't remember why I can't do this, but when I will know this I will write it here).

So basically I just want to have the height of the inner div to be the same as the height of the outer one.

So, apart from the one mentioned by me (`height:inherit` or `height:100%`), is there any other way I could achieve the thing I want?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just set the inner div to have the same height as `px` instead of `%` as the outer div?

```
.popup-body {
    width: 450px; 
    height: 460px;
}

.my-content-div {
    overflow-y:scroll;
    height:460px;
}
```

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/feitla/jZdka/

Comment: I could, but I am reluctant to this soulution because this would mean that I need to put the height in 2 places: 1: in javascript where popup is created and 2: in css.

Comment: Well, you said it yourself... your options are really limited and if you don't declare anything the default values will be inherited. If the popup size will always be consistent, then yes .. you'll need to declare it in 2 places but then won't have to really to touch it again.